# Problems referencing a Net Standard GDAL library from Net Framework

Tags: c#, gdal, .net-standard

I have a `.Net Standard 2.0` libray using `Gdal.Core 2.3`. I can reference it successfully from a `Net5` project, but I get a "*Gdal.Core dll not found*" error if I reference it from a `Net Framework4.7.2`. If I manually add the `Gdal.Core.dll` to the Framework project I get a "*Unable to find an entry point named 'CSharp_OSGeofGDAL_AllRegister___'*" error.

I have tried using the standard GDAL library on the Framework project and the Gdal.core package on the .Net Standard class. Also, I have also changed different versions, created minimal projects and did a lot of testing, but I am not able to make it work. Any advice

Answer (score 0):

I finally realized I had the same issue with all libraries referenced on the Standard project and not only GDAL. This problem was related with the way Nuget packages are handled in the old .Net Framework and the .Net Standard. The solution is to migrate from the old Nuget.confi system, to the new PackageReference system used in .Net Standard.